# Python multiprocessing and shared memory: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SharedMemory'

Tags: python, memory, concurrency, multiprocessing

I'm working on a Python project where I need to use multiprocessing and shared memory to efficiently process large amounts of data. However, when attempting to use the SharedMemory class from the multiprocessing module, I encounter **an AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SharedMemory' error**. I'm confused because I thought SharedMemory was a valid class in the multiprocessing module. Can someone please shed some light on this issue and provide guidance on how to properly use shared memory in multiprocessing?

**Code snippet:**

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def worker(shared_memory):
    # Perform some operations using shared memory

if __name__ == "__main__":
    shared_memory = mp.SharedMemory(name='my_shared_memory', create=True, size=100)
    # Rest of the code...
```

**Expected behavior:**
I expect to be able to create a shared memory segment using SharedMemory and use it within the worker function to process data concurrently.

**Error message:**

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SharedMemory'
```

**Additional information:**

Python version: 3.11

Operating system: Windows 10

I have verified that the multiprocessing module is imported correctly without any syntax errors.
Any help or insights on how to resolve this issue and successfully utilize shared memory in multiprocessing would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try: `multiprocessing.shared_memory.SharedMemory`

Answer (score 0):

Import statement is slightly off. Try:

```
from multiprocessing.shared_memory import SharedMemory

def worker(shared_memory):
    # Perform some operations using shared memory

if __name__ == "__main__":
    shared_memory = SharedMemory(name='my_shared_memory', create=True, size=100)
    # Rest of the code...
```